# Is there a way to use .displayInline option for SwiftUI Menu?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uimenu

In **UIKit** there is a `UIMenu.Option` `.displayInline` to display **submenus** with **separator**. Is there a way to do this also in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2):

You can create `Menu` separators with `Divider`.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu("Hello world!") {
            Button("Item 1") {}

            Button("Item 2") {}

            Divider()

            Button("Item 3") {}

            Button("Item 4") {}
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]